# Projectile shooting with custom force

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have made a projectile shooting system. I want to shoot an object from position A to B following an indicated path. Everything is working fine except for one thing. The velocity applied on the object is calculated based on the distance between A and B, the value of time is 1 to travel this distance. Meaning that the farther I hit, the quicker it goes. I want to have control of the force applied. Meaning that it should go with my set speed whether I hit near or far. Tried normalizing the velocity and multiplied it by my custom force value, but then it moves away from its trajectory.
(See this link below, no matter how close or far we hit the object. It goes with the same speed while following the trajectory indicated. I want to develop this functionality.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghakilo.trickytrack)

```
Vector3 calculateVelocity(Vector3 target, Vector3 origin, float time)
 {
     Vector3 distance = target - origin;
     Vector3 distanceXZ = distance;
     distanceXZ.y = 0f;

     float Sy = distance.y;
     float Sxz = distanceXZ.magnitude;
     float Vxz = Sxz / time;
     float Vy = 0f;
     
     Vy = Sy / time + 0.5f * Mathf.Abs(Physics.gravity.y) * time;
    
     Vector3 result = distanceXZ.normalized;
     result = result * Vxz;
     result.y = Vy;

     return result;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Physics time!

Velocity is a vector whose magnitude is speed.

If you want to fix the speed at which your projectile starts, that only leaves the direction of the velocity in your hands, so you need to calculate the direction in which you want to *yeet* your projectile.

If you're like me, you shoot straight at the target, so you'd set the direction vector to go from the origin to the target. Which is simply `target - origin`, or what you calculate as `distance`. I'm going to call this `direction` because that's what it really is being used for.

Now to use this as the direction vector for your velocity, convert `distance` to a unit vector (not sure how you do this in the unity framework, but `direction.Normalize()`?)

Then multiply this by the speed to get your velocity vector!

```
Vector3 calculateVelocity(Vector3 target, Vector3 origin, float speed)
 {
     Vector3 direction = target - origin;
     direction.Normalize();

     Vector3 result = direction * speed;

     return result;
 }
```

Comment: Hi Pranav. Thanks for the quick answer. I already tried it and have mentioned it in the last two lines of my question. It surely gives me control over the force but then the object does not follow the trajectory that it should have.

See this link below, no matter how close or far we hit the object. It goes with the same speed while following the trajectory indicated. I want to develop this functionality.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ghakilo.trickytrack

Comment: Following your code, it shoots straight towards the target and not in a projectile path.

Comment: Does your current function run once when the projectile is launched to calculate its launch velocity or does it run at every timestep to give the current velocity of the projectile?

Answer (score 0):

First add `rigidbody` to your bullet and set the gravity scale to .5

and add this code to your bullet prefab

```
Vector3 calculateVelocity(Transform target, Transform origin, float time)
    {
        Vector3 direction = target.transform.position - origin.transform.position;
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(origin.transform.position, target.transform.position);
        result = direction.normalized * distance * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        return result;
    }
```